# Wordpress - display a picture different on desktop versus mobile

Tags: wordpress, image, display

on my website I have this picture called *how to use* (see [www.crickmeup.nl](http://www.crickmeup.nl)) and it does show good on desktop but it looks to small on mobile. Therefore I would like to upload a different picture for desktop then for mobile phone. Unfortunately the theme I use (Nantes) doesn't have this option. How can I solve this with changing codes?

Comment: Without changing code?  Ummm...  you'll have to search for a plugin that'll add that functionality for you.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for your reaction. I would actually like to change the code. How can I solve this problem with changing code?